# In Play [2.4.x] is it possible to detect a Twirl template's actual file name?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I wish to place markers in the output of HTML (only during development) such that I know exactly which templates and snippets are being called at any given time. (It's huge and growing library...)

Currently I have something like this:

```
@if(tkAuthenticatedRequest.isDev) {<!-- mystuff.myform.helpers.snippet.scala.html -->}
```

This works of course but is prone to error or omission.

Can we detect the actual filename and have it bleed thru automatically?

Is there perhaps a better way to attach this to dev and not need the authentication at all? While I've `lazy val`'ed the isDev call so it only has a single hit nonetheless I'm open to better ideas.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like `@this.getClass().getName()`, but I don't know what it will return in a template file...

Comment: That my friends almost kinda works! It gives the "view" name of the template. E.g. the name you would use to call it in a template. It doesn't seem to take into account any submodule paths etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic answer if you want the actual file name is as follows:

```
@if(tkAuthenticatedRequest.isDev) { 
  <!-- @Option(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()).map(x => x.getLocation()) --> 
}
```

Note that Twirl has a hard time digesting this unless it is split into three lines so you might want to make a Util function out of it and just pass this.getClass() to that function.